# Is it possible to mount GCP storage bucket as a mount point in DataBricks which is also in the same project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, databricks, gcp-databricks

"I have a requirement where I need to mount the GCP storage bucket on the GCP-Databrciks cluster but I can't find any appropriate documents on it; my intention is to use that bucket as an external table location"

Comment: Hi Shahid, do let me know if my recommendations were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks mounts create a link between a workspace and cloud object storage, which enables you to interact with cloud object storage using familiar file paths relative to the [Databricks file system](https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/external-data/gcs.html). Tight integration with Google Cloud Storage, BigQuery and the Google Cloud AI Platform enables Databricks to work seamlessly across data and AI services on Google Cloud.To read or write from a GCS bucket, you must create an attached service account and you must associate the bucket with the service account when creating a cluster.Connect to the bucket directly with a key that you generate for the service account.
For documentation for working with mounted GCS bucket, see [Mounting cloud object storage on Databricks](https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/dbfs/mounts.html)